# Python:How to save two csv file within a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, finance, quantitative-finance

I am trying to save my stocks analysis result in a better way to view. There are 2 ways I actually want to save my analysis in csv (either one will do for me)

1. save part1 momentum analysis and part2 MACD analysis in a csv file. Both analysis in a line only.EXample: `AAPL,momentum,250.45,active,No cross,MACD above 0`
2. save part1 and part2 in separate csv file with **header**. Then merge both csv into one csv file.

I would prefer the first solution as it just need to save it into a file but I am unable write it a a row using writerow. And I have plan to add on 3 to 4 parts analysis and combine them.
The code below is for solution 2 but I have **problem putting the header**. The header for part1 which I label as hdm and part2 (haven't put in the script) are different and it can not be in the for loop as it will repeat the header.
Please help me on what is the best way for this code. Thanks!

```
      import pandas as pd
      import numpy as np
      import csv
      import datetime
      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      import talib as ta

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        KLSEData = ['AAPL','MSFT','IBM','WDC','STX','EMC','NCR','XRX']
        KLSElen = len(KLSEData)

        hdm = ['Stock','Mom','Pct','Liquidity']
        csvout = open('stock_mo'+now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".csv", 'a')
        csvwrite = csv.writer(csvout)
        csvwrite.writerow(hdm)

        for x in range (1,len(KLSEData),1):
            data = pd.read_csv(KLSEData [x][0]+".csv", index_col='Stock', usecols =[0,6,7])
            high =  pd.read_csv(KLSEData [x][0]+".csv", index_col='Stock', usecols =[0,4])
            h=np.array(high['High'])
            low =  pd.read_csv(KLSEData [x][0]+".csv", index_col='Stock', usecols =[0,5])
            l = np.array(low['Low'])
            close =  pd.read_csv(KLSEData [x][0]+".csv", index_col='Stock', usecols =[0,6])
            c = np.array(close['Close'])
            vol = high =  pd.read_csv(KLSEData [x][0]+".csv", index_col='Stock', usecols =[0,7])
            v = np.array(vol['Volume'])
            #data = pd.read_csv(KLSEData [x]+".csv", index_col='Stock', usecols =[0,7]) 
            print data.head(3)
            vol1 = data['Volume']
            print vol
            volmean5 = pd.rolling_mean(vol1,5)
            #print volmean5
            volmean20 = pd.rolling_mean(vol1,20)
            #print volmean20
            mo_ratio = volmean5/volmean20
            print mo_ratio[-1]
            mo_pc = (mo_ratio[-1]-1)*100
            #print mo_ratio
            MACD = ta.MACD(c)


    #part1 momentum analysis
            if mo_ratio[-1]>= 2.5:       
               print '+ve momentum'
               active = vol.tail(30)==0
               """for y in range (len(data)-30,len(data),1):
                   active=[data.iloc[y,1]==0]"""
               if any(active):
                  csvwrite.writerow([KLSEData [x][0]]+["  momentum "]+["%.2f"%mo_pc]+["not active"])
                  csvout.close()
               else:
                  csvwrite.writerow([KLSEData [x][0]]+["  momentum "]+["%.2f"%mo_pc]+["active"])                 
                  csvout.close()
            else:
               print 'no momentum'  

            #part2 MACD analysis
            csvout1 = open('stock_macd'+now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".csv", 'a')
            csvwrite1 = csv.writer(csvout1)        
            if MACD[2][-1]>1e-08 and MACD[2][-3]<MACD[2][-2]<MACD[2][-1]:
               if MACD[0][-1]>MACD[1][-1] and MACD[1][-1]>0.0:
                  csvwrite.writerow([KLSEData [x][0]]+["Golden Cross"]+["MACD above 0"])
                  csvout.close()
               else:
                  csvwrite.writerow([KLSEData [x][0]]+["Golden Cross"]+["MACD below 0"])
                  csvout.close()               
            else:
               if MACD[0][-1]>MACD[1][-1] and MACD[1][-1]>0.0:
                  csvwrite.writerow([KLSEData [x][0]]+["No Cross"]+["MACD above 0"])
                  csvout.close()  
               else:
                  print "No MACD signal"
```

My desired output:

```
AAPL,momentum,250.45,active,No cross,MACD above 0
MSFT,momentum,130.59,not active, Golden cross,MACD above 0
```

Current output:

```
Stock,Mom,Pct,Liquidity

AAPL,  momentum ,251.77,not active

AAPL,No Cross,MACD above 0

Stock,Mom,Pct,Liquidity
MSFT,  momentum ,251.77,not active

MSFT,No Cross,MACD above 0
```

Comment: Why dont you write records in a `dataframe` and then do `df.to_csv` instead of using `writerow`?

Comment: @RohanAmrute, If I use df.to_csv, how will it fix my problem?

Comment: I am suggesting you write your data in a `dataframe` rather than using `writerow`

Comment: @RohanAmrute, 'dataframe' and 'writerow' in csv file, is it different? Please elaborate more as I am not familiar with this..thanks

Comment: I add the desired ouput in csv and also the current output. Thanks